# Apache, include correct "Server" header when proxying

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I got the following section in mine httpd.conf

```
<virtualhost *>
    ServerName my.domain.com
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.193/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://my.domain.com
</virtualhost>
```

The problem is that apache replaces the "Server" header with it's own IP address.
How do I force it to use "my.domain.com" in the server header?

Comment: Are you referring to the `Server` header that is passed to the client, or to the upstream HTTP server?

Comment: I'm referring to the server header that is sent to the upstream HTTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProxyPreserveHost On